# How to Updating rowHeight table google slide api

Tags: php, google-api, row, google-slides-api

I'm using Google Slide API to generate presentation, and I want to create table using this API, I try this function to do it and it worked well, but it create table with `"rowHeight": { "magnitude": 3000000, "unit": "EMU" },`
I want to modify this value, But I didn't found how.
The G-slide API has just this fields to insert new row :

```
'insertTableRows'=> array(
    'tableObjectId'=> $tableId,
     'cellLocation'=> array(
          'rowIndex'=> $rowIndex
      ),
      'insertBelow'=> $insertBelow,
      'number'=> $number
)
```

When I use this function I got the problem above.